# Evaluating Variables first in PowerShell Commands

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to get PowerShell to evaluate variables before executing a command, for example:

```
$OutputPath = "C:\Temp"  
Get-ChildItem -include *.mp3 | Move-Item -Destination $OutputPath
```

However, the Move-Item cmdlet tries to interpret this literally, so it doesn't get moved. The script works fine whenever I enter the path directly, but I need to be able to control the path with a variable. How do I do this?

Comment: What exact error you got?

Comment: The code you posted should do what you expect it to do.

Comment: I would also like to know the error. There shouldn't be anything wrong with the code posted.

Comment: My guess is the use of  `-include`.... that works better with `-Recurse`. Change it to `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp3` or just remove the parameter name `Get-ChildItem *.mp3`. I think that Move-Item is not getting anything from the pipe.

Comment: @Matt whenever I add -Recurse, I get this error: `Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\Windows\Temp\MediaMover.ps1:10 char:47
+ Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.mp3,*.m4a | Move-Item -Destination $OutputPath
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\Exit the Premises.mp3:FileInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand`

Comment: So is your working directory c:\temp then?

Comment: @Matt C:\Users is my working directory, although I have changed it around and put media files in C:\Temp to test it, with no more luck. Also, I tried the script typing it in (Versus running from the ISE) without the pipe, and Move-Item asked me for the path, so as my original suspicion was, PowerShell isn't evaluating the variable before running the script. That's what I need to know how to do, as I can get the script to function simply by swapping out the variable.

Comment: Well the error is explicit. The file is already there. You can use `-Force` to overwrite (use with caution) and `-WhatIf` to help with testing.

Comment: Is the $OutputPath variable spelled correctly (that is, consistently) in your script? You might like to add `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` at the top of your script to catch that sort of error.

Answer (score 3):

This answer could evolve but as your question stands I see a big issue that is unfortunately poorly documented. `-Include` and `-Exclude` only perform their intended functions when partnered with `-Recurse`. Used without it can yeild 0 results. In your case that would mean nothing is passed through the pipe and `Move-Item` is not executed.

Currently you are just filtering on `*.mp3` which is basic and can just be used with the `-filter` parameter. While you don't need to I would recommended specifying `-Path` as well so that you move the files you wanted.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp3 | Other-Stuff ...
```

You mentioned in comments the following error:

```
Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

That error is **very** specific. Either from previous testing or an oversight in new names that file indeed already exists. Two things you can do to help with that problem is use the `-WhatIf` switch which should quote a file path on the verbose stream so you know where the file would end up.

Second, if you understand the data risk, is to use `-Force` so that the file will be overwritten by the new one. With `Copy-Item` it is not a big deal since the original file still exists. Mistakes with `Move-Item` can be permanent.

Comment: Using the `WhatIf` just returns the script's normal functions, and it finds the media files just fine. However, now, whenever I changed the path, it just creates a generic file with my output folder's name instead of actually moving the files.

Comment: @DreadEurosRot You have to show an example of that code in your question and add detail if you can. I can't explain what it is happening with your setup with what I have so far.

Comment: @DreadEurosRot, you should create a folder, before move files to it.